# Internet speed is slower when connected to mains

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, broadband

I have noticed that my internet speed as tested on www.speedtest.net drops significantly when my computer is connected to mains.

My average speed on mains (several runs) is 11.6 Mbit\s, on battery it is 51.6 Mbit\s. This is calculated over 5 runs with interleaved trials. No change is seen in upload speeds which are both around 16 Mbit\s (here the mains even has a slight advantage - 16.9 vs. 15.8). Pings are also roughly equal.

I am on a Dell XPS 15 (9530) model on a Windows 8.1.

Comment: most likely AC hum on the data line causing more packets to fail.  maybe better grounding is needed.

Comment: What is most likely the source of a ground problem like this?

Comment: Do you use Powerline to connect your computer to the (rest of the) Internet? Or Wireless? Or a real cable straight to the modem/router? Something else, perhaps?

Comment: I am connecting to router via wireless.